# Can't uninstall Visual Studio 2013 RC

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to uninstall Visual Studio 2013 RC on Windows 7 using Programs and Features, but it just gets as far as the splash screen before crashing. The specific error is "Setup has detected an issue during the operation. Please click here to check for a solution..."

I've tried using the original installer from the ISO, but the same thing happens. Even running the installer from a cmd prompt using /uninstall as a parameter causes the same thing.

Any ideas?

Error Details:

```
Problem Event Name: VSSetup
  P1:   vs_professional
  P2:   12.0.20827.03
  P3:   12.0.20827
  P4:   Modify
  P5:   unknown
  P6:   Crash: Exception
  P7:   5174ddfb
  P8:   2bf
  P9:   25
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    6153
```

Error log:
http://pastebin.com/hUd6BFoz

Comment: A log file should have been created.  We need to know what error was reported in order to help you.

Comment: I've added in the error details from the crash window. I don't know where to even begin looking for a log file.

Comment: If you "click here to check for a solution", does it offer any suggestions? Have you tried them?

Comment: @techie007 Yes it just submits the details to Microsoft. There's no solution available.

Comment: @karoma - I would start by removing VS2013 component one by one through `Add/Remove Programs`

Comment: Did you try a "Repair" install?  Did you check the actual (un)install logs (`%temp%\dd_xxx.log`)?

Comment: @techie007 Yes I tried a /repair from cmd, same result. I've found that log file. I'll update the original post with a link to it

Comment: There's a lot of 0x80070570 errors in that log file. [0x80070570 = "ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT - The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable"](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0x80070570).  Have you done a disk check to ensure there's no current disk and/or file system corruption?  They all seem to be related to the VC++ runtimes, so have you tried removing/reinstalling the [Runtimes for VC2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40784)?

Comment: @techie007 Chkdsk came back clean. The 2013 runtimes weren't even installed, but I installed them anyway, but no change. I've just removed all runtimes and still nothing.

Comment: Strangely the problem was with the Roboto font from Google. After deleting it everything uninstalled fine!

Comment: @karoma Bizarre! You may want to post that as an actual answer (you're allowed to answer your own questions :) ).

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question since I've low rep, but I'll do it later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird what it ended up being -- for others that stumble here (unrelated to font issues) -- you can also try "/Uninstall /Force" from the command line -- might also be a "/Repair /Force".  Additionally, you may want to vote on this feature: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3487794-create-a-remove-all-remnants-of-visual-studio-fro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough the problem was with the Roboto font from Google. After deleting it everything uninstalled fine.

Answer (score 0):

Run the installer from the CD or your downloaded setup file as Administrator. You'll have the uninstall option at the bottom.